# Bizarre behavior in the for loop using their stride iterator

Tags: swift, integer, ieee-754

It seems it's an IEEE issue

but I didn't think that -0.2 + 0.1 would qual `-0.0999999999999996`

so what I am doing is creating a coordinate map of (-3,-3) to (3,3) where intervals are 0.1. I can simply solve this issue by rounding the results (and I can enhance it by only rounding when there are more than 1 decimal)

I wish I didn't have to though as that adds checks on every loop, and it runs 3721 times.

```
for x in stride(from: min, to: max + 0.1, by: 0.1) {
    for y in stride(from: min, to:max + 0.1, by: 0.1) {
        let rounded_x = Double(round(x * 1000) / 1000)
        let rounded_y = Double(round(y * 1000) / 1000)
        print("\(rounded_x), \(rounded_y)")
        coordinates[Coordinate(x: rounded_x, y: rounded_y)] = []
    }
}
```

even stranger, this only occurs for -0.2 + 0.1, here's the full output of the inner loop:

```
3.0, -3.0
3.0, -2.9
3.0, -2.8
3.0, -2.7
3.0, -2.6
3.0, -2.5
3.0, -2.4
3.0, -2.3
3.0, -2.2
3.0, -2.1
3.0, -2.0
3.0, -1.9
3.0, -1.8
3.0, -1.7
3.0, -1.6
3.0, -1.5
3.0, -1.4
3.0, -1.3
3.0, -1.2
3.0, -1.1
3.0, -1.0
3.0, -0.9
3.0, -0.8
3.0, -0.7
3.0, -0.6
3.0, -0.5
3.0, -0.4
3.0, -0.3
3.0, -0.2
3.0, -0.0999999999999996
3.0, 0.0
3.0, 0.1
3.0, 0.2
3.0, 0.3
3.0, 0.4
3.0, 0.5
3.0, 0.6
3.0, 0.7
3.0, 0.8
3.0, 0.9
3.0, 1.0
3.0, 1.1
3.0, 1.2
3.0, 1.3
3.0, 1.4
3.0, 1.5
3.0, 1.6
3.0, 1.7
3.0, 1.8
3.0, 1.9
3.0, 2.0
3.0, 2.1
3.0, 2.2
3.0, 2.3
3.0, 2.4
3.0, 2.5
3.0, 2.6
3.0, 2.7
3.0, 2.8
3.0, 2.9
3.0, 3.0
```

I'm not sure why this occurs in the stride function, but not when adding -0.2 + 0.1, and that is what I am curious about.

Comment: If you need higher precision you can use decimals otherwise just display a user friendly description using NumberFormatter

Comment: aren't I already using decimals?

Comment: I meant Decimal type instead of Double